# Pumping Lemma with Prime Number

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, pumping-lemma, primes

$\text {Could someone please help me with this proof: }$
$L:=\left\{a^{n} d^{m} b^{k} | n, m, k \in \mathbb{N} \wedge m \text { is a prime number}\right\}$

$\text {Maybe we can say, that } w=a^{n}d^{m_s}b^{k} \text { and } d^{m_s} \text{ is a prime number with } |w| \ge n. \text{And we choose xyz arbitrarily with } w= xyz \text { } \wedge |y| \ge1 \wedge |xy| \le n\text {. And now I don't know how to go on. Maybe someone can help me, please.}$

Comment: What is the question? Be or not to be a regular language, or a context-free language?

Answer (score 1):

Helpful property of prime numbers: The gaps between consecutive prime numbers become arbitrarily large. That means for every r, there is a prime p such that none of the numbers p+1 to p+r are primes. That means $a^nd^mb^k$ is not in the language for p+1 ≤ m ≤ p+r.

That would generally work for "m is a member of an infinite set with arbitrarily large gaps between members of the set", like "m is a square, a cube, a factorial" and many others.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it by carefully picking $w$ and a bit of counting.

Let $q$ be the first prime greater than or equal to $p$, and let $w = d^{q}$ (the $a$s and $b$s are really a bit of a red herring - here we're just choosing $n=k=0$ to get rid of them).

Then by the rules of the pumping lemma, $y = d^{t}$ for some $1 \leq t \leq p \leq q$. We can then pump up $q$ times, giving $w' = d^{q-t}d^{t}d^{t\times q} = d^{(t+1)\cdot q}$. Clearly $(t+1)\cdot q$ is not a prime, so $w' \notin L$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's more plausible now.